# Which has greater +R strength - toluene or anisole?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I read that resonance in toluene is initiated with the help of hyper-conjugation. Also hyper-conjugation is weaker than resonance/mesomeric effect. But, in toluene, its resonance is taking place with the help of hyper-conjugation, am I right? I am confused which has greater +R strength - toluene or anisole?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Short answer: Anisole should have the greater +R effect, because the oxygen atom in anisole has delocalized electrons that can participate in resonance. Hyperconjugation $\ne$ resonance; hyperconjugation is a way to explain inductive stabilization. Toluene will have a greater +I effect.

Comment: @BenNorris  I thought hyperconjugation = resonance.  The same rules apply, can't move nuclear positions, etc.  I thought the inductive argument for touluene was based on the electronegativity difference between an $\ce{sp^3}$ methyl group carbon being connected to an $\ce{sp^2}$ aromatic carbon.

Comment: So what is the final answer ?

Comment: I have not forgot, but alas, this is a busy time for me.